# Only "latest" temporal version to generate triples through TDE

Tags: marklogic, temporal, marklogic-9

As far as I can see, all the versions of a temporal document generate triples when using TDE.

How is it possible to restrict them to the collection `latest`?  I do not want to have triples from past versions when I SPARQL.

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of temporal documents will be in the ["latest" collection](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/temporal/intro#id_74266). You can specify the [collections](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE#id_81078) of a view in the template definition. Define the template to use the "latest" collection and the temporal collection to extract the latest documents. The snippet below shows a template which will index nodes from the "latest" and "temporal-collection" collections.

```
<tde:template xmlns:tde='http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde'
              xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
              xsi:schemaLocation='http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde'>
  <tde:context>/</tde:context>
  <tde:collections>
    <tde:collections-and>
      <tde:collection>latest</tde:collection>
      <tde:collection>temporal-collection</tde:collection>
    </tde:collections-and>
  </tde:collections>
  <tde:enabled>true</tde:enabled>
  <tde:rows>
    <tde:row>
      <tde:schema-name>myschema</tde:schema-name>
      <tde:view-name>myview</tde:view-name>
      <tde:columns>
        <tde:column>
          <tde:name>mycolumn</tde:name>
          <tde:scalar-type>string</tde:scalar-type>
          <tde:val>myvalue</tde:val>
        </tde:column>
      </tde:columns>
    </tde:row>
  </tde:rows>
</tde:template>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was afraid of that answer.  I guess more generally, the question is about "how to deal with triples and temporality?"  Is it better to generate triples only for latest (but then, what about triples embedded in documents?), or is it rather better to restrict every single query to `latest` (but then, what about queries using temporal and non-temporal triples?)

Comment: Damn, I miss the ML Dev mailing list so much, SO is not well suited for this kind of question/discussion :-(

Comment: @FlorentGeorges That's certainly a discussion worth having. I'd suggest asking another stackoverflow question on the topic.